# How to transfer encrypted information with non repudiation and message integrity in REST

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, architecture, restful-architecture

Someone asked this question to the author of this article but didn't get an answer, does someone have an answer:

https://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=6432484966567158349&postID=3673658851645058486

JK said...
"•Despite being simple, REST is fully-featured; there's basically nothing you can do in Web Services that can't be done with a RESTful architecture."

So how do you set up a transactional web service having a secure context to transfer sensitive information that is encrypted with non repudiation and message integrity within the message body without using SOAP?

Please don't say SSL, that is Transport level, not message level.

Comment: There are no WS-* specs to help you here and no framework to implement them (searching online you will probably find various attempts for this but no generally accepted solution). So basically there is nothing built for REST for you to use in this regard. The answer is: you have to build them yourself.

Comment: @Bogdan OK I'll build myself but how to start :)